# cakephp Ajax form does not work when type is POST

Tags: ajax, forms, cakephp, post, prototypejs

I developed a site using cakephp 1.1, It has a lot of ajax elements tu update multiple elements simultaneously and they worked pretty well.  Now, I am migrating to cakephp 1.3, but I am not having such a great experience.

Thanks to this [blog](http://schneimi.wordpress.com/2007/10/27/update-multiple-fields-with-one-ajax-request-response/) I was able to get multiple divs updated, but soon I got stuck again.

My current problem is with an ajax form which does not complete the request to the url '/logs/logIn' ('/controller/action').

After submiting the form, Firebug shows me an error: "POST http://localhost/logs/logIn 404 not found", the request is interrupted in the function request() of prototype, line 1530:

```
this.transport.send(this.body);
```

When I write the url directly in the browser, the site seems to work as I would expect.  And when I change the type of the form from 'POST' to 'GET' the ajax request is completed and the response is the one I expected, but I DO NEED to do it with 'POST'.

I have read a lot of forums in which similar issues are discussed, but no suggestion has help me to solve the problem:

- I have checked my hhtp.conf and .htaccess files, they seem to be fine according to the installation instructions (but I am not sure).
- The action I am requesting does not use any view (in fact, 'GET' and direct url requets function whit no need of the log_in.ctp view file), and I have created the respective view when I try the 'POST' ajax request, but It still does not work.

I am using the latest version of scriptaculous and protoype.js (1.7), I am working with Firefox 3.6.17 on ubuntu.

Many thaks in advance for any trick, tip, advice or whatever you can do to help me.

Answer (score 3):

I finally got the problem fixed.  It had to do with cake's Security component.

All I did was to set the $validatePost variable to false.

I had understood the post valiation was applied to 3rd party posts, but It seems cake does do the validation for enery post request, even the ones originated in the principal app.