# Equivalent of $_POST in CakePHP for ajax calls?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, post

Normally, when I'd do an ajax call to a page with jQuery's $.post(), I'd post to a specific page (i.e. ajax.php) with something like:

```
var submissionId = 1;
$.post('/ajax/ajax.php', {
        submissionId: submissionId
}, function(data) {
alert(data);
});
```

and inside ajax/ajax.php, I'd manipulate the data how I'd want with `$_POST['submissionId']`. What is the equivalent to this in CakePHP if I'm posting to a controller?

Do I still use `$_POST['submissionId']` or `$this->data`?

If using `$this->data`, do I need to create a `<form>` to wrap the event handler in?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6362349/143295) might answer your question.  Setting `validatePost` to false will let `$_POST` act as normal in your CakePHP application.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where he defined that variable and set it to false? Within the controller he is posting to?

Comment: It would be set in the beforeFilter callback of that controller: `function beforeFilter() { $this->Security->validatePost = false; }`. You might find [this post](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:u1uaN0lsF4EJ:blog.endpoint.com/2009/12/using-security-component-and.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) helpful (assuming you're using 1.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create form with cake helper (hide it with css or jquery if you don't want it to be there) and use [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)
you can submit the form with jquery with submit()
so in the controller you can use $this->data

Comment: I don't know a lot about CakePHP, so I don't blame you if that is the only way, but creating a form and *hiding* it with styling sounds like a really kludgy solution.  Styling shouldn't be used like that. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: I too would like to know the answer to @Renesis's question above. This is the only way to pass data and use it w/ $this->data? CakePHP is looking uglier all the time to me.

Comment: there is another way to do it (to use $this->data in controller without the form trick). You can use firebug to inspect the form's inputs' name the helper generate or inspect the post request and look at the data. They look like data[something][0][something] or data[something][something]. You can use json to post those data.

Comment: @hope_is_grim this won't work because I just want to send arbitrary data without using Cake's built-in formhelper.

Comment: i mean {data: {submissionId: submissionId}}